# I want to make Excel 2010 change year in the cells was written Date on the way of hand

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have sheet in Excel, with cells having dates like:

```
1/1/2018
2/1/2018
3/1/2018
4/1/2018
```

I want to change just the year by writing in any cell like as

```
2019
```

So that Excel changes the cells' date but just year only like this

```
1/1/2019
2/1/2019
3/1/2019
4/1/2019
```

Please help me to do this

Comment: You could do a search for `2018` and replace it with `2019`

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to using find and replace. But if you are interested you can try the following.

Excel detects the system date as current date.

If you press ctrl + ; in any of your cell. It will print the current date. Which means the date is coming from control panel.

**Windows 10**

In the search box on the taskbar, type control panel, and then select Control Panel.

Under Clock, Language and Region, click Change date, time, or number formats

1. Click Regional and Language Options.
2. In the Region dialog box, click Additional settings.
3. Click the Date tab.
4. And Change it to 2019.

But doing this you will be ending up with many date issues.

Method 2:

You could write a VBA function on the worksheet change event wherever 2018 is found then  change it to 2019.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DATE` function with a reference to another cell for the ***year*** argument.

> Syntax: DATE(year,month,day)
>
> https://support.office.com/en-us/article/date-function-e36c0c8c-4104-49da-ab83-82328b832349

So in your case, enter the year (`2018` or  `2019`) in e.g. Cell `B1`, and use the formula like this:

`=DATE(B$1,1,1)`